# Formation de tirelo/virelo

Tags: vocabulaire, néologismes

Dans *Le pont de Londres :*

> Tu nous diras où qu'il se trouve le joli bateau **tirelo** ! (p. 625)

J'avais imaginé que *tirelo* était formé par emprunt au refrain *tire lon laire*. Tout de même, je ne comprends pas très bien sa fonction dans cette phrase.

Quelques pages après l'on peut lire aussi :

> Ça voltige pourtant aux abords, ça roupille pas, ça pivote, hausse
> dans les pavois, à toute ficelle, la camelote cascade de partout, ça
> bourlingue du tillac en poupe, oh hisse ! par-ci ! **virelo** ! là !
> des cataractes de colis qui s'engouffrent (...). (p. 629)

À votre avis, ce *virelo* a la même formation et fonction du mot précédent, *tirelo* ?

Answer (score 1):

Ça « sent » le « hisse et oh » et le « virer de bord », mais pour ce qui est de quelque chose de spécifique ça a plutôt l'air d'être le néant ; on pourrait penser plutôt à une mimique de chant de marin, dans lequel "hisse et oh" est un leitmotiv. ([Santiano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYyaKNvcKEA))

Comment: Un des deux se trouve là-dedans : https://www.proquest.com/openview/326f7e98d0bfe850395ffbfb1b0cba93/

Comment: @viande-à-chien [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/virer) :  **a)**  Virer au treuil. virer au guindeau,  
 Virer à pic.  Virer sur l'ancre.
**b)** Virer de bord.